# Interfaces Comparator y Comparable. Java

Tags: java, ordenamiento, comparaciones

Mi pregunta es: ¿Es estrictamente necesario que a la hora de usar Comparable implementemos la interfaz sobre la clase en sí en la cual queremos establecer el criterio de comparación y ordenación para cuando la invoque sort() mediante compareTo()?

¿O podría crear otra clase en la cual le paso los parámetros y el me devuelve lo que me interese ordenado? Pregunta al revés para Comparator, ya que los ejemplos que me han dado siguen esa pauta y al probar a hacerlo al revés en ambos casos no parece funcionar y me tiene algo mosqueado por que tal vez se me escape algo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si intentas ordenar una lista por los métodos de la clase utils Collections 
de la siguiente manera `Collections.sort(list)` y la clase de los objetos de lista no implementan la interface `Comparable`, pueden ocurrir 2 cosas:

- No compila, si la lista es tipeada y el tipo no implementa la
  interfaz `Comparable`.
- Se lanza una excepción `ClassCastException` en tiempo de ejecución.

Por eso debe implementar `Comparable` como ordenamiento natural o por defecto de los objetos.

Si quieres ordenar la lista por otro criterio de ordenamiento distinto al ordenamiento natural debes implementar la interfaz `Comparator` y ordenar de la siguiente forma `Collections.sort(list, comparator)`.

por esta razón si quieres ordenar una lista con la clase utils Collections.sort debes implementar una de las dos interfaces Comparable para el caso Collections.sort(list) o Comparator para el caso Collections.sort(list, comparator)

Puedes encontrar mas información en la documentación en [Ordenamiento Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html)