# Ordenar alfabeticamente una list de objetos por el atributo nombre de cada uno de ellos

Tags: java, lista

Necesito ordenar una lista alfabeticamente pero no me aclaro con el Collections.sort(). os dejo lo que tengo

```
public class Propietario {

    private String dni;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private String direccion;
    private String telefono;
    private String nacionalidad;
    private String email; 

public List consultarPropietarios(ObjectContainer db) {
        Propietario propietario = new Propietario();
        ObjectSet res = db.queryByExample(propietario);
        List<Propietario> p = res;
        Collections.sort();
        return res;
    }
```

en el metodo obtengo un tipo de lista la igualo para que el resultado de la query sea una lista de propietarios y tener acesso a sus atributo pero ya no se seguir no se que meterle al Collections

Comment: Implementa `Comparable`ó `Comparator`; revisa [ésta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/135805/interfaces-comparator-y-comparable-java).

Comment: Podrias hacer el Sort en la consulta a la base de datos, tip!

Comment: es muy jodio porque es db4o y no es facil

Answer (score 0):

Ups disculpa te lo respondi corriendo y no me fije en la sintaxis(ortografia),
ahora si:

```
public static SortedSet<Propietario> consultarPropietarios(ObjectContainer db) {
    Propietario propietario = new Propietario();
    ObjectSet res = db.queryByExample(propietario);
    SortedSet<Propietario> oredenedList=new TreeSet<Propietario>(new Comparator<Propietario>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Propietario p1, Propietario p2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return p1.getNombre().compareTo(p2.getNombre());
        }

    });
     oredenedList.addAll(res);
     return oredenedList;
}
```

Ahora no se que se lo que hace el ObjectSet, si lo que almacena es un Collection no deberias tener problema.
Prueba ahora a ver. Pra recorerlo haces esto.

```
for (Propietario p : Proietario.consultarPropietarios(db)) {
        System.out.println(p.getNombre());
    }
```

Comment: no me lo admite dice can no find symbol y que espera un punto y coma